# rails test:models error in RailsTutorials, Chapter 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through the tutorial 
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users and in Chapter 6 have run into a problem when running the code in Listing 6.6, e.g.,

```
rails test:models
```

in the console I get the error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `models' for main:Object.
```

I tried this with similar results:

```
2.3.0 :010 >  @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: 
"user@example.com")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, 
remember_digest: nil, admin: false, activation_digest: nil, activated: 
false, activated_at: nil, reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil> 
2.3.0 :011 > @user.name
=> "Example User" 
2.3.0 :012 > @user.email
=> "user@example.com" 
2.3.0 :013 > @user.valid?
=> true 

2.3.0 :016 > NameError: undefined local variable or method `models' for 
main:Object
```

What's the problem/solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you executed `rails test:models` from inside the Rails console.

Any `rails` or `rake` commands should be executed outside of the console, i.e. the same way you execute `rails console`.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem and solution.